# Line Width of Resonance Peak in NMR Experiment

Tags: magnetic-fields, experimental-physics, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

I'm studying the NMR experiment at the moment and was wondering what the line width of the resonance peaks represents? When I've looked into it, it just comes up with the definition that it's 'the full width at half-maximum', but could someone explain what it actually means? I.e. what does a large line width entail?

Comment: try this site  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Atomic/broaden.html